Integrating Google Earth Engine (GEE) data into a Flutter app
How do I display Relative humidity map image produced by a GEE JS file in a Flutter App? I want to take country name and time as a user input and display the image accordingly.
Link to the GEE file: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8bd0bc03bf042500de6565c6dac8a866

For integrating GEE into web pages you should create apps: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/apps
